# redireccionar a un pagina de error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo el siguiente código realiza la conexión y consulta a la bd sql server:

```
public DataTable ejecutarComandoConsultar(SqlCommand varComand)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapatador = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conexionServidor.Open();
            adapatador.SelectCommand = comando;
            adapatador.Fill(tabla);
            return tabla;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;   
        }
        finally { conexionServidor.Close(); }   
    }
```

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando surja algún error en la conexión, no le muestre el error al usuario, si no que le muestre una vista.
he intentado añadiendo en el web.config lo siguiente:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Reportes/error" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

pero no me funciona.
gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cambiar tu configuración por la siguiente:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Reportes/error" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Reportes/error" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Recuerda que el `error 404` se activa cuando el usuario intenta buscar un recurso o URL que no existe en cambio el `error 500` se lanza cuando ocurren errores internos del servidor.

Comment: no me funciono.

Comment: @BryanG. Haces la llamada al método usando controles POSTBACK o vía ajax?

Comment: utilizo ambos para acceder al controlador... pero ahi no es donde tengo el problema, es en el model cuando hago una llamada a la bd

Comment: Ok. Con lo que tienes hasta ahora, cuando se lanza el error de la base de datos, el servidor te está mostrando el pantallazo de error genérico de IIS o simplemente no se está mostrando ningún mensaje de error?